# search a word in 2d array movement is only top-bottom and left-right in java

Tags: java

Given a 2D matrix of characters and a target word, write a function that returns whether the word can be found in the matrix by going left-to-right, or up-to-down. For example, given the following matrix: 
`[['F', 'A', 'C', 'I'], ['O', 'B', 'Q', 'P'], ['A', 'N', 'O', 'B'], ['M', 'A', 'S', 'S']]`
and the target word 'FOAM', you should return true, since it's the leftmost column. Similarly, given the target word 'MASS', you should return true, since it's the last row.

Comment: i could do it for all eight directions using back tracking but donot know how to do for 2 directions

Comment: Please post some code that you already have tried and specify which part you are having trouble with. Just posting a question like this makes it look like you want someone to just do your homework for you. If you try it yourself and need help on something that you've tried, it's much more likely that someone on SO will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 
public class Exercise6 
{ 
    static int R, C; 
    static int[] x = { 1, 0}; 
    static int[] y = { 0, 1}; 
    static boolean search2D(char[][] grid, int row, int col, String word) 
    {  
            if (grid[row][col] != word.charAt(0)) 
                return false; 
            int len = word.length();  
            for (int dir = 0; dir < 2; dir++) 
            { 
                int k, rd = row + x[dir], cd = col + y[dir];  
                for (k = 1; k < len; k++) 
                { 
                    if (rd >= R || rd < 0 || cd >= C || cd < 0) 
                        break; 
                    if (grid[rd][cd] != word.charAt(k)) 
                        break;  
                    rd += x[dir]; 
                    cd += y[dir]; 
                }  
                if (k == len) 
                    return true; 
            } 
        return false; 
    } 
    static void patternSearch(char[][] grid, String word) 
    { 
        for (int row = 0; row < R; row++) 
        { 
            for (int col = 0; col < C; col++) 
            { 
                if (search2D(grid, row, col, word)) 
                    System.out.println("pattern "+word+" found "); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
            R = 4; 
            C = 4; 
            char[][] grid = {{'F', 'A', 'C', 'I'}, 
                {'O', 'B', 'Q', 'P'}, 
                    {'A', 'N', 'O', 'B'}, 
            {'M', 'A', 'S', 'S'}} ; 
            patternSearch(grid, "ABNA"); 
            System.out.println(); 
            patternSearch(grid, "MASS"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: If your code, please move the source code to your question. You can doing that by clicking on edit link underneath your question. After that delete this post.